# Why is the dump function in R not creating a file?

Tags: r, dump

When I dump values into a file "dump.R" shouldn't it be listed in the directory?

```
> x<-"foo"
> y<-1
> dump(c(x,y),file="dump.R")
> list.files()
[1] "Workbook1.csv"
```

Comment: try `?dump`  as MrFlick has spelled out  for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dump` function takes a vector of names of variables, not the variables themselves. Try

```
x<-"foo"
y<-1
dump(c("x","y"),file="dump.R")
list.files()
```